# How to force VSCode to ignore linting the next line of golang code?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, lint

I like my code to look clean.  I try to follow recommendations, etc.  It helps keep everything tidy, conforming, and decent.

But sometimes, you need to defeat the linter because it has a bug, or it just doesn't understand what you intend.

In this case, I have the following code:

```golang
fmt.Println("Enter values between %00 and %0f.")
```

VSCode complains with:

```
fmt.Println call has possible formatting directive %0f (printf)
```

That's a reasonable thing for it to think, and I thank it very much for warning me of a possible mistake I might have made... but in this specific case, I really do want it to print `%0f` as-is.  I really, really know what I'm doing here.

Normally, I might do something like this:

```golang
//lint:ignore printf No, really, this is what I want
fmt.Println("Enter values between %00 and %0f.")
```

But VSCode still gives the yellow wavy line and completely ignores the lint:ignore directive.

I must work around this annoyance with:

```golang
fmt.Printf("Enter values between %%00 and %%0f.\n")
```

But I'd prefer to use the original syntax, as the intent is clearer, and the line matches what I've written everywhere else in this part of the overall code.

So, how do I put my foot down and freaking tell the cursed program to stop placing its errant yellow wavy line because, dammit, I really do know what the I'm doing?  It is not only distracting, but it wastes my time as I keep looking over the 'linting error' only to see it's not an issue.

*Edit*

Some additional information might be useful.

In my desire to keep things as uncomplicated as reasonably possible, I use the 'Go' extension, with no changes to the linter it defaults to using.

Examining these settings, it looks like it's using `staticcheck`.  And, indeed, I see that in the local bin folder.

But `staticcheck` doesn't care.  It doesn't complain at all about the `fmt.Println()` I wrote, even if I don't have a `//lint:ignore` line above it, when I run it explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that this specific check is made by `go vet`, not `staticcheck`, and `go vet` [intentionally](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17058) does not have a mechanism to ignore checks.

Comment: I strongly disagree with what I read out there, but oh well.  Not my product.  Maybe I should explore a way to disable vet, if it's 'broken' (from my perspective).

Comment: I agree. I understand striving for no false positives, but that's essentially impossible. My project trips a “this implements ReadByte with the wrong signature”. I know I'm implementing someone else's interface in a mock: I have to use their wrong signature.

Comment: In my specific case, what should be an optional warning has become a non-optional warning that threatens to make me ignore all warnings.  Classically, one places a comment to disable a warning, with a follow-on comment explaining why the warning isn't applicable.  That many people do not do this shouldn't influence a decision to force warnings like this.  But, again, not my product.  I can choose not to use it if I must.